# Generic function type alias

Tags: typescript

Why in TypeScript type alias doesn't work with a generic function?
For example, here TS doesn't define type Identical as generic.

```
type Identical = <T>(v: T) => T;

const identical: Identical<string> = (v) => v
```

I know that correct variant is:

```
type Identical<T> = (v: T) => T;
```

But why first example doesn't work and what type of `T`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript generics: Inequivalence of generic function type and call signature of an object literal type (Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230133/typescript-generics-inequivalence-of-generic-function-type-and-call-signature-o)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In what follows I will use the word "specific" to mean "not generic".  Usually people say "concrete" for this, but I'm concerned that someone will think that means "not `abstract`", and this has nothing to do with `abstract` classes.

---

*Other than generic functions*, TypeScript only has generic *types*, not [generic *values*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574).  For a generic type, the type parameter is written in angle brackets after the type name:

```
type GenericType<T> = {x: T};
```

You can have a generic type like `Foo<T>`, but any actual *value* of that type must be specific, with an actual specific type specified as `T`:

```
declare const badValue1: GenericType; // error, requires 1 type argument
declare const badValue2: GenericType<T>; // error, cannot find name 'T'
declare const goodValue: GenericType<string>; // okay
```

Note that `GenericType<string>` is now a *specific* type, equivalent to `{x: string}`.  So once you specify generic parameters in a generic type by plugging in specific types, you get a specific type out.

---

Generic functions are different: a value of a generic function type is generic.  It acts as the full family of different specific function types.  For a generic function type, the type parameter is written in angle brackets before the function parameter list:

```
type GenericFunction = <T>(x: T, y: T) => void;
```

A generic function's type is not necessarily generic itself; there is no type parameter on the `GenericFunction` name above.  So you cannot specify the generic type parameter by addingYou specify the generic function type parameter only when you *call* the function:

```
declare const badFunc: GenericFunction<string>; // error, GenericFunction is not generic
declare const goodFunc: GenericFunction; // okay
const ret = goodFunc<string>("okay", "fine"); // okay, type parameter specified as string
const ret2 = goodFunc("okay", "fine"); // also okay, type parameter inferred as string
```

---

So, the difference between these:

```
 type IdGenericType<T> = (x: T) => T;
 type IdGenericFunc = <T>(x: T) => T;
```

is that the first is a *generic* type which will refer to a *specific* function when specified, while the second is a *specific* type which refers to a *generic* function.  These types are not equivalent, although they are related.  You can assign a value of type `IdGenericFunc` to any variable of type `IdGenericType<XXX>` for any specific type `XXX` you want:

```
let id: IdGenericFunc = x => x;
let idString: IdGenericType<string> = id; // okay
```

But not vice versa:

```
const otherId: IdGenericFunc = idString; // error! T not assignable to string
```

Which makes sense, because an `IdGenericType<string>` is only known to accept and output a `string`:

```
idString = x => x + "!"; // okay
```

So you can't assume that an `IdGenericType<string>` is a valid `IdGenericFunc`.  The relationship between `IdGenericType<T>` and `IdGenericFunc` is that `IdGenericFunc` is essentially the *intersection* of `IdGenericType<T>` *for all possible `T`*:

```
// type IdGenericFunc = forall T. IdGenericType<T>; // invalid syntax
```

But there's no way to express that directly in TypeScript (I borrowed the `forall` syntax from [Haskell](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types#The_forall_keyword)).

---

See the [TypeScript GitHub issue on generic values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) for more info.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgFXBAPBgfFALxQDeUAHgFxQZQC+A3AFDMAmEaANgIZLRoA9vADOwKACMebAGo8uAVwgBGGnESpM2RlAD0uqMiSCkAGij8AjgpT8RUZVFCQofAOYKAtgmDtOvfighUXEpWXklACY1BGR0LEg8fB19QyRjMyCeeHhBcQAzFHg2KHgebygAcgxKv24+AWExKDdBQXDFCBiNeOwcMVR4N2S9A0EAax4QVmdodTi0ADEFeDRgFGFiKCSACmpacxAaDABKYkIAN0EUNhY6gMaQyWll1e6F17WN+H7gQeGUgYjCZzPNNJ91psUPZcuI3LFNPcGkEmnC2mxPu9wSsvsJAVAJlNmMFmvxxCRWu1Pr9-vgdgAiQkgenmemFRD0k74pnmWZQMB8coQYDIKAiSBoFCFCAlHj2AZFNzE1EWYWRLaUjE4hlMllQNlFCCc-HyESCAmTEC87D8wXeEVIKBFfJGGWueV-RWsZh8gCSbDBvUSBC2e2OZyIhAwLD9AYR6E+W12+1O51ody4wqdbBo-sDSxxWwoaYoLEz4huAGVPUNc3GelpEgqhoQSDduZbmFWa24iyWoABqfUAQnpHaJJPEeQAFsh-XX84m22xq-98cCkMPaKU8u6RCg3GUJJmnObm0rmKlY4vCyR8iZ5FxaAA6KB5+ON3AEfFFC7yG5iiA8DADwFDekAA)

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks for taking the time to explain it